# Modify all web URLs with PHP - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to do a "mass search" of all the URLs on the web to put a parameter at the end of each link.

Example:

```
1- If there is a string that starts with 'http
2- End with a quote (')
3- Does not end with .mp4, png, jpg
4- Then, add the string . "&mobile" before the quote (').
```

Do you understand my point? Basically I want to add to all the links the parameter of mobile.

Can you help me? I can't figure out how to do it.
(I'm a newbie to PHP, so I apologize if it's basic)

## Update

My code:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['mobile'] ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adaptabilidad-nattule', plugins_url( 'css/mobile.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0' );
    
    
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'adaptabilidad_nattule_add_mobile_url' );
    function adaptabilidad_nattule_add_mobile_url( $content ) {
        $url = get_permalink();
        $content .= 'href="' . $url . '?mobile"';
        return $content;
    }
}
```

If I enter my website:
mysite.com/?mobile

That function is activated. What I want is to change all the links that appear with the ending of ?mobile

Comment: I think that you need to edit the question to make it clear. What do you mean by "search the web ? ".

Comment: Check the update please.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked your question with a WordPress tag. I will assume that  you need to perform a WordPress Search and Replace

1 . there's a WordPress CLI command that fits your need
https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

2 .  if you want to write PHP code, use PHP preg_replace() Function

Comment: Check the update please.